# devise+omniauth devise helper like current_user,user_signed_in? not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I am using devise and create login with Facebook using omniauth, but having problem of lost the devise helper methods access like current_user and user_signed_in? methods are not working.

### EDIT

### AuthenticationController

```
def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]    
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth["provider"], omniauth["uid"]) ||       User.create_with_omniauth(omniauth)    
    session[:user_id] = user.id    
    redirect_to dashboard_path(user.id), :notice => "Signed in!"    
end
```

redirect_to USercontroller dashboard method

### UserController

```
before_filter  :logged_in

 def dashboard    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])   
    @comment = Comment.new    
    @comments = @user.comments.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)    
 end
```

so here control should go to dashboard method after checking logged_in method in ApplicationController

logged_in method in ApplicationController

### Application Controller

```
def logged_in    
    if user_signed_in?     
       return true    
    else    
       redirect_to root_path    
       flash[:message] = "please login"    
    end     
  end
```

when I logged in using facebook following code generated at console

```
Started GET "/users/52/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 29 12:51:55 +0530 2012     
Processing by UsersController#dashboard as HTML     
  Parameters: {"id"=>"52"}     
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/     
Filter chain halted as :logged_in rendered or redirected     
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

in the above code control is render from logged_in method to root_path but it shold render dashboard_path

So I am guessing User_signed_in? helper is not working I also use current_user in stead of that generate same error

Comment: how exactly are they not working? undefined method? and is normal login with devise (I mean without FB) working or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I see, `user_signed_in?` is working, but returns false, as for Devise user is not logged in. To fix this, just replace the session id storing with Devise `sign_in` method in your controller action:

```
def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]    
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth["provider"], omniauth["uid"]) ||       User.create_with_omniauth(omniauth)    
    sign_in(:user, user)

    # actually if you really really need that id in the session, you can leave this line too :)
    session[:user_id] = user.id 

    redirect_to dashboard_path(user.id), :notice => "Signed in!"    
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but can you please tell me what is sign_in(:user, user) and how it should affect Device?

Comment: it's a [Devise helper](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in-instance_method) to manually sign in a user with Devise ([wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-from-a-controller)). The problem with session[:user_id] is that first: Devise uses different key in the session, and second: there's happening smth more then just storing id in the session. If you are interested, you can always check internals

Comment: Thank for your answer you are life savior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using `sign_in user`, and I had to add `:user` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the user account via Facebook, how do you sign in the user?

You should still be using devise helpers like `sign_in_and_redirect`. Something like:

```
user = User.build_from_omniauth(omniauth)
if user.save
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
end
```

Then you should be able to use helpers like `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` (which just check if `current_user` is not nil).

---

Taking a look at your edit, my answer is still valid. What you need to do is use `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)` instead of just setting the id in the session.
You can easily customize where the user is redirected after sign in with devise.

Another thing, remove this logged_in filter, Devise has a `authenticate_user!` method that you can use as a before_filter. It will redirect the user to the sign in page, and when they login, it will redirect them to the page they were trying to access.

You're using Devise, so try to take advantage of that, and go read the doc ;)